# How to register app in uber for developers

Tags: uber-api

I can't create an app in uber for developer.
I try to follow the [steps](https://developer.uber.com/docs/businesses/guides/getting-started#register-your-app)

And when I click in "SIGN IN" I'm redirect to a page where I have to fill in my email and password and get in my own account, of user! Normal user!

Some one now how to register an app on Uber developer?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific "developer login". The steps outlined on the page you linked are indeed the correct steps:

Sign into the Uber developer portal at developer.uber.com
Click Register App
Select Rides API
Enter in a name and a short description
Agree to our terms and conditions

You just login at developer.uber.com with a normal Uber rider account...your own account (email / password). Hope that helps.

Comment: OK! But this is not "Click Register APP" in portal.

Comment: On my rider account there is no "Click Register App" too kkkkk

Comment: I'm not following, just sign in at https://developer.uber.com/ (sign in button in upper right). Sign in with your Uber account, then there is a 'new app' button. Cheers.

Comment: OK! I loged me in at developer.uber.com, clicked in SIGN IN, ask me to confirm my mobile number and I went redirected to my uder account, but there is no "Click Register App"... Look the photo on the description here.

Comment: The screenshot you posted is from https://riders.uber.com (not the developer site). If you are having trouble verifying your mobile number (nothing to do with the Uber API) perhaps try downloading the Uber app and verifying there. If you are still having trouble you could reach out via Twitter at @uber_support.

Comment: can you send me a screenshot of the screen with this "new app" button? Because I already try everthing to create the app and nothing. Someone told me I have to update my business account to Premium to do this.

Comment: No problem. To get to this screen, I went to developer.uber.com and clicked "sign in". Signed in with my Uber account. Then there is a "new app" button:  http://imgur.com/a/b3QQu

Comment: Man! It is very very strange because every time I log me in by developer.uber.com a screen asking I confirm my mobile number and then I am redirect to my user accont and there, there is no new app button. I don't understand, realy.

Comment: Confirming your mobile number is unrelated to the Uber API. This would be an Uber login issue. If you are having trouble confirming your mobile number, I would recommend downloading the app (if you have not already done so) and also looking at help.uber.com: https://help.uber.com/h/87ce1f38-62ab-4820-b022-b458eb05cbcf  If you are still having trouble, you can also reach out to uber general support on twitter at @uber_support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the Uber App and confirm your phone number from there.
After confirming, you will get the option to create new app.
I was also facing the same issue and after downloading the app, the issue was resolved.
Hope it helps someone with similar issue.